# how do I optionally not run a cucumber feature

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I want to *not* run certain cucumber feature if, say, I'm on windows.  Google and the cucumber docs seemed to turn up dry so appealing here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The best way to approach this would likely be using tags.

For example, if you add a tag like `@not-windows` to a feature you can then customize your cucumber execution to ignore this.

```
@not-windows
Feature: Your feature that causes a problem
  your scenarios
```

If you then run your tests with `cucumber --tags ~@not-windows` it will run all cukes that are not tagged by @not-windows. The ~ is what causes the "not" behavior, you could run ONLY these tags by doing `cucumber --tags @not-windows`. Using the first cucumber line while in Windows, you can block the problematic features (or individual scenarios) from running but if you're on another OS and run cucumber normally, these will still be ran.

Reference: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags

Answer (score 19):

Supporting Tyler's answer I would like to propose this additional information:

### Use [Cucumber Profiles](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/cucumber.yml)

If you are running the system on multiple different environments you may want to create a profile file and then simply define a default profile for you which excludes the file.

```
# config/cucumber.yml
##YAML Template
---
windows: --tags ~@not-windows
default: --tags @not-windows
```

Execution (on a non-windows system / default)

```
$ cucumber
```

Execution (on a windows system):

```
$ cucumber -p windows
```

You could set the default to whichever environment you are currently on to save yourself having to remember which features do not executing; allowing you to just execute `cucumber`.

### Use [Cucumber Rake Task](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Using-Rake)

Create a rake task that checks your environment and includes the tag you want:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'cucumber'
require 'cucumber/rake/task'

WINDOWS_PLATFORM = /mswin|win32|mingw/ unless defined? WINDOWS_PLATFORM

Cucumber::Rake::Task.new(:features) do |t|
  tags = (RUBY_PLATFORM =~ WINDOWS_PLATFORM ? "~@not-windows" : "@not-windows")
  t.cucumber_opts = "features #{tags}"
end
```

Execution (on either platform):

```
$ rake features
```

This should automatically include the right tag based on your environment.